# WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: java, richfaces

com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase execute INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be the id field for `<rich:message for="startDate"..../>` .

```
<rich:calendar buttonIcon="/img/calendar.gif"
                                    **id="startDate"**
                                    value="#{gererExtensionController.startDate}"
                                    datePattern="#{common8DController.datePattern}"
                                    disabled="#{gererExtensionController.dateDisableStartDate}" /> 
                                    <rich:message **for="startDate"**... />
```

The `"for"` field should be same with `"id"` for the attribute.
In this scenario also, the WARNING message is displayed.